# Scrolling programmatically breaks LinkedIn In-app browser

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, linkedin-api, inappbrowser

I have a page that automatically scrolls down by a few pixels every few milliseconds.

**Example-code:**

**JS:**

```
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    document.scrollingElement.scrollTop += 2;
  }, 10);
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <p>lMagna minim consectetur ex occaecat id laborum voluptate culpa consectetur consectetur ex consectetur occaecat aliqua consectetur do. Sunt duis sit eu reprehenderit labore reprehenderit excepteur enim ad. Ipsum ut irure sint cillum culpa dolore excepteur sint Lorem dolore aute duis voluptate adipisicing enim dolore. Aliquip officia proident aute ea non nulla cillum occaecat exercitation dolor irure sint fugiat non est consectetur. Duis ipsum magna elit fugiat voluptate consectetur duis ea reprehenderit quis elit eu eu. Incididunt elit fugiat id eu consequat in labore deserunt occaecat. Reprehenderit veniam in nisi qui ipsum id irure enim reprehenderit proident laborum quis. In ipsum excepteur aliquip do fugiat sint laborum eu deserunt aute commodo ullamco  </p>
  <p>Aliquip minim ipsum mollit dolor ea sint officia occaecat aliqua ullamco adipisicing minim reprehenderit dolore ex mollit. Nostrud do non excepteur et et Lorem non duis commodo. Ut voluptate esse ullamco mollit voluptate Lorem nulla. Nisi sint eiusmod voluptate commodo sit aliqua sint laborum deserunt quis ex labore culpa amet velit. Commodo reprehenderit adipisicing fugiat anim nulla et veniam mollit amet duis do laboris voluptate. Eu in aute do ipsum non est velit officia ipsum dolor eiusmod ipsum sit qui ad incididunt. Ad ullamco eu irure eu dolor eu mollit. Eu pariatur qui ut eu esse veniam veniam pariatur Lorem.</p>
  <p>Sint occaecat id nulla id enim sunt aliqua. Adipisicing excepteur voluptate nisi elit mollit eu officia nisi incididunt aliquip proident labore Lorem ex officia incididunt ad. Magna in amet Lorem quis esse et consectetur. Duis aute magna nisi nulla aliqua anim elit nostrud cupidatat ut officia veniam quis elit cillum. Sit reprehenderit ullamco laboris occaecat Lorem esse commodo pariatur sit adipisicing tempor sit magna deserunt eu. Tempor excepteur reprehenderit occaecat laborum nisi ullamco voluptate incididunt voluptate eiusmod esse. Enim ea eiusmod sit occaecat sunt incididunt do ea aliquip enim ut do in ea.</p>
  <p>Amet eiusmod commodo aliquip laborum Lorem deserunt fugiat ullamco in laboris exercitation anim id anim dolore voluptate aute. Eiusmod ipsum exercitation ullamco qui ut aliquip nulla. Non eu aute esse minim culpa eiusmod sit ut mollit deserunt id adipisicing commodo voluptate. Excepteur non Lorem ipsum ullamco Lorem voluptate id non laboris laborum.</p>
  <p>Nostrud amet aute irure eiusmod velit mollit tempor Lorem deserunt esse officia commodo. Elit cupidatat eu ut dolor do occaecat irure duis ipsum amet quis anim. Occaecat aliqua ad deserunt non Lorem enim ea aute reprehenderit eu amet aute dolor mollit.</p>
  <p>Ullamco eu consequat in culpa anim esse ad tempor quis nisi irure occaecat duis enim. Ea nisi cupidatat duis dolor mollit aliqua labore ea eiusmod. Cupidatat consequat qui consequat velit ullamco fugiat cillum officia ullamco reprehenderit non. Fugiat sit enim anim et proident incididunt ut officia veniam commodo. Amet magna aliqua ad culpa nisi quis et nulla velit anim.</p>
  <p>Minim aute adipisicing exercitation minim ad cillum enim ut veniam. Aliqua veniam reprehenderit aliquip reprehenderit consequat laboris enim ad magna Lorem excepteur adipisicing. Sunt Lorem ex ad minim sint nulla laborum exercitation commodo quis ea consectetur nisi deserunt eu. Est ea incididunt proident occaecat id sint nostrud incididunt.</p>
  <p>Cillum officia dolor elit duis cillum ullamco proident anim aliquip. Pariatur sit esse dolore ipsum duis incididunt incididunt fugiat consequat eu anim ad ut velit laborum aute nostrud. Et qui aliqua ea enim veniam anim pariatur exercitation fugiat nostrud reprehenderit. Amet elit est reprehenderit anim exercitation nostrud adipisicing et amet reprehenderit enim. Exercitation et fugiat qui esse laborum cillum occaecat ullamco incididunt exercitation quis occaecat anim ut irure aute sit. Laborum qui eu aliquip proident labore eu commodo laboris est cupidatat. Ea sunt incididunt eiusmod commodo ut duis in.</p>
</div>
```

The above code works as expected in every regular browser (Desktop Firefox, Desktop Chrome, Mobile iOs Chrome, Mobile iOs Safari, ...).

Opening the same page in the LinkedIn In-App Browser however makes the app freeze as soon as the bottom status-bar is about to disappear (which happens because of scrolling). So it executes and scrolls fine until there are about 2 or 3 visible pixels of the bottom browser-bar left. Than the whole app freezes and needs to be closed manually.

*Every method I tried results in a freeze of the In-App browser*:

```
window.scroll(  0, ...);
window.scrollTo(0, ...);
window.scrollBy(0, ...);
```

Changing the amount to scroll and the interval don't make a difference either.

Attaching the scrolling to a clickhandler also crashes the app as soon as the next scroll-event would make the bottom bar disappear.

I'm fairly certain this is a bug in the LinkedIn-app related to how the in-app browser displays and calculates the position of the browser-bars.

Is there another way to scroll using JS or - even better - could the lovely devs of LinkedIn please fix this if it is actually related to the way they handle scrolling?

Comment: You can try increasing the height of page using css as soon as you are reaching bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not exactly about reaching the bottom of the page.  
The browser bar behaves similar to the mobile safari bookmark bar at the bottom of the screen. It disappears after scrolling down for at least x pixels (around 50 I guess), regardless of the position on the page.